# Multiple background images not working in IE8 and IE7

Tags: css, css3pie

Below is a simple code in which I have implemented multiple background images to body, but this code does not work in IE 7 and 8 whereas it works in all other browsers. I have used PIE.htc which is relative to the html document,but still no success. Please help me to solve this example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style="background: url(header_top_border.png) repeat-x, url(bg_1px.jpg) repeat-x;  behavior: url(http://localhost/mutliple_bg/PIE.htc);
-pie-background:url(header_top_border.png) repeat-x, url(bg_1px.jpg) repeat-x; position:relative; zoom:1; z-index:1;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry hasty read of your question, just noticed your using pie.
PIE doesn't support multiple backgrounds on BODY element;

Solution: create div container for body.

Comment: Was able to give multiple background easily by using a container and body tag, but my aim was to use PIE.htc which could have helped with multiple background images in IE7,8. Does it mean that PIE.htc doesn't support multiple background property for IE7,8. Please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple backgrounds are only supported by IE9 and above.

Answer (score 0):

use div position`relative and absolute`

i think this is the easy way to fix cross browser problem hope it help...

click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/WR9Ge/) for working fiddle

html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="colorLeft"></div>
    <div class="contentArea"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#555;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
.colorLeft {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;    
}
.contentArea {
    width:400px;
    background-color:#fff;
    height:180px;
    margin:10px auto;
}
```